# WPF dialogbox to select file or folder

Tags: wpf, dialog

I would like to know if there is a way to let an user when he clicks on a button "select file or folder", letting him choose a file or a folder as he wishes.
I know there is way to make a select file or a select folder, I would like to do it in one way where the user either choose a file, either choose a folder, and then in my code, I get either the file or the list of files of the folder.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sucks, but I think you will need to make your own OpenFileDialogue and use the Directory class.

```
   using System.IO;

   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
   string[] dirPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

The directory class has some useful things that will make this process a little easier.

Comment: ok, can you please explain me a little more your solution. I would like to open a dialogbox where either the user select a folder and click ok or either some or one files in the folder and select ok. Inthe first case, you will get a liste of string path of all the files in the folder, and in the second case, you will get a list of string path of only the selected files.

Comment: OK make a new window or something with a list box. Add both those lists to the listbox, and when a user selects something, check if it is a file or folder (Can be done with directory class I believe) and do with is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

create a class `FolderPicker` then code it like this >>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoRunGenerator
{
    class FolderPicker
    {
        public static string FileName = "";

        public FolderPicker()
        { 
          OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult dr= ofd.ShowDialog();
            string filename = ofd.FileName;
            FileName = filename;
        }
        public string GetFileName()
        {
            return FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

**then**
call it from your event method or from anywhere like this >>

```
FolderPicker fp = new FolderPicker();
txtBox.Text= fp.GetFileName();
```

i hope this will help for file dialogue box

Comment: The fact you name it as "FolderPicker" does not make it magically allow to select folders. OP asked for multi purpose dialog, you just wrapped file dialog into your own type.